# How to autopopulate the field of a table in MS Access with a Identity created in seperate table

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am building a form in MS Access using linked ODBC tables which is to become a large input basis for some of our teams. I have most of it worked out however am trying to auto generate a Primary ID for the main table and populate the text box so the agent doesn't have to. Effectively building an auto number in SQL.

I have the generation and rolling edits in the ODBC tables working and am just stuck on getting the generated code into the relevant field. I am using a macro on button click and have the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmitDetails_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim para As String

para = InputBox("Please Enter Your User ID:")
strSQL = "SELECT Min([P_ID]) AS ID FROM QA_IDS WHERE EV_ID = " & para & ";"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
Me.ID.Text = rst!ID

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing


End Sub
```

Me.ID is the field I am trying to populate. It is erroring out in the line

```
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

with the error Run-time error '3464' Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

It's my first real dabble in MS Access and I've searched for the solution online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible your criteria expression `WHERE EV_ID = " & para & ";"` has a data type mismatch? Perhaps it is not expecting a string? Anyway, you may  be better off setting default values through the Access design gui.

Comment: Thanks for this. To test it I changed the query to a hard value and it worked. Although the input is a number i.e 55231, the datatype in the ODBC table is a VarChar so I was expecting string to work. Is there a different datatype that would be a more likely match?

Comment: I also tried building the query with a parameter in Access then using "SELECT * FROM qrySELECT_MINIMUM_ID" but it errored with expected 1 parameter got 0, is there a way to set the parameter with an Input Box or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I was trying using a different method and thought I would post for someone to find useful in the future.

To get around the issue of inconsistent datatype I used a query to run the SQL (including inputting the User ID) , and append it to a new table. Then pull the information from that table with a DLookup, then purge that table. I ended up with the following code.

```
Private Sub cmdSubmitDetails_Click()

Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Dim z As String

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("AppendID")
x = DLookup("[ID]", "[TempID]")
Me.ID = x
y = DLookup("[EV_ID]", "[TempID]")
Me.EVALUATOR_ID = y
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qryDELETE_TEMP_ID")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qryAddNextCallID")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qryDELETE_MINIMUM_ID")
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```